# Modify view inside event handler before view ready

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

When my nativescript application starts, I have a class that is responsible for the login and sends me events to notify of the current state. During the login process (it usually takes 1 to 5 seconds), I'm receiving many update events and have to display a busy indicator so that the user knows that something is happening...

My problem is that when my events are fired, the user interface is not yet ready (I suppose that the `afterViewInit` has not been called at this time) and for this reason, the `hide`/`show` method of my `LoadingIndicator` generates exception.

I'm using the `LoadingIndicator` from `@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator`. Here an example of my event handler in my home-page.component.ts :

```
private onUserLogin(info: LoginInfo): void {
   if (info == null) {
      this.loadingIndicator.show();
   } else {
      this.loadingIndicator.hide();
   }
}
```

I'm not sure about the solution. It doesn't seem to be a good idea to do a loop with a `setTimeout` in my `onUserlogin` event handler to wait that the `afterViewInit` event has been fired.....

Comment: What outcome are you trying to get here, do you want to show the loading indicator? Or just handle the exception? If the latter I would suggest just wrapping the loadingIndicator function calls in a try/catch block.

Comment: I have to display it since the login is being processed (I want to inform the user). At least as soon as the view is ready.

Comment: Well you could set an `isLoaded` flag to be true in `afterViewInit`, then only call the loadingIndicator functions if this is true? Or you could only set `onUserLogin()` as the login handler in `afterViewInit` (I don't know how you're calling `onUserLogin()` though, how are you?).

Comment: Like a wrote, `onUserLogin` is an event fired by another class that tells me that the login is being processed. It can be fired at any time, also when the view is not initialized, this is exactly the problem.... My current workaround is a dirty solution with a setTimeout waiting for a flag being set to true (in the afterViewInit method...)

Comment: Well then I'd got for the `isLoaded` flag method.

Comment: This is what I wrote at the end of my question. Have the impression that this is more a workaround that a good solution? Basically a while loop with a setTimetout().....

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a timeout, more like this on the first line of onUserLogin(): ```if (!this.isLoaded) return;```

Comment: Where is `onUserLogin` defined, and who calls it?

Comment: @colliere I can't do that, because executing  `if (!this.isLoaded)` will return false and my code will never be executed. I have to call it in a loop until the flag `isLoaded' is set to true and this would be a workaround, I'm looking for a better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with anything asynchronous in Angular the recommended pattern is to use a shared service with a [BehaviorSubject()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html). This decouples the asynchronous events from components, and allows the components to focus just on the visual side effects.

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    public info$ = new BehaviorSubject<LoginInfo>(null);

    public onUserLogin(info: LoginInfo) {
        this.info$.next(info);
    }
}
```

You can now subscribe to these events from the component, but do so when the view is ready.

```js
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    private destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

    public constructor(private login: LoginService) { }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
       this.destroyed$.next();
       this.destroyed$.complete();
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
       this.login.info$.pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
       ).subscribe(info => {
           if (info == null) {
               this.loadingIndicator.show();
           } else {
               this.loadingIndicator.hide();
           }
       });
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! actually this is more or less what I'm doing, I should have post more code in my question, my bad... The only difference with yours is that I'm subscribing in the `ngAfterViewInit` event rather than`ngOnInit` and that I'm doing a `unsubscribe` in the `ngOnDestroy`, but it's still not working (but the `setTimeout` workaround mentioned in my question is working)

Comment: This is a problem I already observed in Nativescript, the `ngAfterViewInit` event seems to be fired too soon, at least sometimes. What I did now is subscribing to the `(loaded)` event of my main layout, and put the subscription code inside this handler, and it's working correctly. Weird. Will accept this answer since it helped me to find out the solution....